# Does factoring class functions into modules improve performance in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, class, module, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to clean up the models of my Rails apps by extracting repeating code into modules. I know that makes my code DRYer, but does it make my app more performant? I guess the question would be: is the code from the module loaded in memory once and for all or is it loaded every time it's included in a class? And consequently, is it advisable to include modules into ActiveRecord::Base or should they be included only in classes that need them?

Comment: I can't give definitive answer but I don't think it makes code any more performant. However, as you pointed out, modules/concerns make code much more DRY which is (almost) always a good thing to do. This also allows you to abstract code more so it's easier to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

As [`require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require) is documented to give a different return status when told to load already loaded files, I assume that the code is only parsed once.

As to performance gains: With Java indirection is adding a penalty to method execution, which can become significant, if the method itself is small and is only found some levels of inheritance away.
On the other hand the JVM will try to turn the Java-Bytecode into Native-Bytecode, starting with the most frequently called methods. For JRuby this clearly means that methods, which are only defined once, are more likely to become optimized (early) than other methods.

I don't know the exact behavior of the Ruby-interpreter, but would assume it to also optimize more frequently called methods first.

As with any performance issue I would also assume, that there is no "this is always performing better" and individual benchmarks are needed to find the best approach for every situation.

I would advice to

- do DRY programming, so you can easily adjust your code to new requirements
- look at the performance of the resulting program
- if you are unsatisfied with the performance (and only then)

  1. identify often called functions and long-running functions
  2. try to move these functions directly into the classes or rewrite in a way you generally call less functions

Including modules into classes which don't use them can become irritating and could only boost performance directly after starting the application as the may be parsed earlier. I would advice against doing so.

Comment: Aren't `require` and `include` very different?

Comment: Yes, it seems i was in a bit of a rush. Still I would assume that the code is only evaluated once per file.